# how to subtract two columbs using index in tidyverse

Tags: r

i have a dataframe

```
df <- tibble(row1= c(1,2,3,4,5),
            row2=c(2,3,4,5,6))
```

how do i subtract the two columbs using index (not rownames)? I would like this to work

```
df %>% mutate(diff= select(1)-select(2))
```

But the universe is not on my side....

Comment: Another possibily: `df %>% mutate(diff = get(names(df)[1]) - get(names(df)[2]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` needs a data parameter as the `Usage` is

> select(.data, ...)

Also, as `select` returns a data.frame/tibble as output, we can get the vector with `[[`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(diff = select(., 1)[[1]] - select(., 2)[[1]])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   row1  row2  diff
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2    -1
#2     2     3    -1
#3     3     4    -1
#4     4     5    -1
#5     5     6    -1
```

or instead use `pull` to return the `vector`

```
df %>%
   mutate(diff = pull(., 1) - pull(., 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `select` like below?

```
> df %>% mutate(diff = do.call(`-`,select(.,1:2)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   row1  row2  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    -1
2     2     3    -1
3     3     4    -1
4     4     5    -1
5     5     6    -1
```